# Single line format VS overstepping pagebreak

Tags: ruby, ruby-style-guide

Ruby sets guidelines for best practice but what happens when two guidelines contradict eachother? Which one do you prefer?

For example..

## Option 1 (Not recommended)

```
if some_condition
  do_something
end
```

## Option 2 (Recommended)

```
do_something if some_condition
```

What happens if you use **option 2** and the text goes outside the traditional page break. Which rule takes priority according to the community guidelines?

```
                                                        |
 do_something if some_condition_which_takes_up_a_lot_of_room_is_met                                                       
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                        |
                                                        |
```

Thanks

Comment: Ruby (or its developer) doesn't set best practices, some Ruby community do.

Comment: He probably refers this style-guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Use suffix conditionals only when the line is short.  Do this not to keep the line shorter than an arbitrary limit, but because a long line is probably too complex and should be broken up into smaller, easier to understand pieces.